# Проблема с подключением телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from aiogram import executor
ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/__init__.py)
```

Файла `Main.py`:

```py
from aiogram import executor
from handlers import client, all_users
from bot_data import dp


async def on_startup(_):
    print("Bot Started")


all_users.register_handlers_verification(dp)
client.register_handlers_client(dp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Обновите aiogram

```
pip install -U aiogram
```

Answer (score 0):

executor есть в aiogram 2. У вас же установлен aiogram 3, в котором executor'а нет.
Тут два варианта:

1. Переписать код на aiogram 3, что, как мне кажется, предпочтительней
2. Установить aiogram 2 - pip install aiogram==2.25